# What is the meaning of 퍼트리?

Tags: translation

Specifically 소문 퍼트리. I know that 소문 means rumor, but i can't find 퍼트리 in all translator machine either it's naver papago or google translate

Comment: It's 퍼(지다)+뜨리+다.

Comment: A complete sentence will be '소문을 퍼트리다'. It sounds unnatural if 을 is omitted.

Answer (score 8):

The verb is [퍼뜨리다](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/71b4534284ca4df1ac8e52f7081da36d), although it is sometimes pronounced [퍼트리다] by some speakers.

It means *to spread*.

### EDIT

Actually, [퍼트리다](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/911d5d3b320d4d01881e3c1540ddb388) is also an alternative standard form of the verb.

This generally applies to most verbs ending with [-뜨리다](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/d8afea2a39ca49869eca8c109ed1459f), that you can also say [-트리다](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/8f23b3da3b044dd8b8560b27b2909cdd&directAnchor=s403466p258007d306659).

Answer (score 3):

I believe 퍼뜨리 is just a typo. 
Or, the final letter 다 went missing while copying and pasting.
The person should have written it 퍼뜨리다 or 퍼트리다.

On the second thought,
if the person has used 소문퍼뜨리 to call someone for their behaviors or as someone's nickname while talking on someone's back,
it may mean the person who spreads words.
However, I wouldn't consider this case usual.
Very well could be some teenagers' jargon.